# Swift: iOS Datepicker yyyy vs yy

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a UITableView with two UITableViewCells, that each use a UIDatePicker.

Sometimes, the year format is yy and sometimes yyyy. I can't figure out, why.

Is there any chance to force yyyy?

Thanks.

Created via cellForRowAt (snippet):

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "pickerCell")
    
cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString("DetailView.detailCell.arrival.label", comment: "")
    
let arrivalPicker = UIDatePicker()

arrivalPicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
arrivalPicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime

if errorText != "" {
    arrivalPicker.tintColor = .systemRed
}
else {
        arrivalPicker.tintColor = .systemBlue
}
    
cell.accessoryView = arrivalPicker
    
return cell
```

[image]

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: show the cellForRow method implementation

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: Do you set the datePicker's locale somewhere? I know the date strings depends on the selected locale.

Comment: Although I never had this issue myself, the following part from the docs may be helpful: *Setting the locale changes the language that the date picker uses for display, but also the format of the date and time (for example, certain locales present days before month names, or prefer a 24-hour clock over a 12-hour clock). The width of the date picker automatically accommodates for the length of the localization.*

Comment: Setting the locale to Locale.autoupdatingCurrent didn't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try the following:

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium //set the option you prefer
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium //set the option you prefer
    let date = Date()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK") //set the identifier you prefer
```

Then set the cell content as `dateFormatter.string(from: date)`

Here is the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Comment: I need the datepicker to edit dates, not just a label.